# XSD enumerations on both element and attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have a XML tag, which contains an attribute and content in it.
And I want to check the several possible attributes and the content.

My XML:

```
<Filter>
   <Value type="!NULL">AAA.BBB</Value>
   <Value type="!BLANK">XXX.YYY</Value>
   <Value type="!EMPTY">AAA.BBB</Value>
   <Value type="!Content">XXX.YYY</Value>
</Filter>
```

My XSD:

```
  <xs:complexType name="ValueType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="!NULL" />
              <xs:pattern value="!BLANK" />
              <xs:pattern value="!EMPTY" />
              <xs:pattern value="!Content" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

With this XSD I validate the attributes... but how can I expand it and force it to validate the content like "AAA.BBB" and "XXX.YYY" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The following XSD demonstrates how to use enumerations on both an attribute and element content,**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Filter">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Value" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ValueType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="ValueType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="ValueContentType">
        <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:pattern value="!NULL" />
              <xs:pattern value="!BLANK" />
              <xs:pattern value="!EMPTY" />
              <xs:pattern value="!Content" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="ValueContentType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="AAA.BBB" />
      <xs:pattern value="XXX.YYY" />
      <xs:pattern value="AAA.BBB" />
      <xs:pattern value="XXX.YYY" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

**and will validate your XML,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="try2.xsd">
   <Value type="!NULL">AAA.BBB</Value>
   <Value type="!BLANK">XXX.YYY</Value>
   <Value type="!EMPTY">AAA.BBB</Value>
   <Value type="!Content">XXX.YYY</Value>
</Filter>
```

**successfully, enforcing enumerations on both an attribute and element content as requested.**

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot! Now I also understood how and why to use <xs:extension>!